# Modify a string into a date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that opens a `*.CSV` file and copy the content to a tab of my `*.xlsm` for further analysis.

Dates in the CSV are in the following format : `dd.mm.yyyy 00:00:00`

My locale is English (HK) therefore dates are `dd/mm/yyyy`

The CSV cells are not recognized as dates (so far, it is normal). When I open it with the VBA code, I have set `Local:=True`

as the CSV has 50k+ lines, I do not want to go one by one so I tried the following :

```
wbO.Sheets(1).Columns("C:C").Replace What:=" 00:00:00", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
wbO.Sheets(1).Columns("C:C").Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But the dates are then recognized but as `mm/dd/yyyy`, in other words, my `02.01.2020 00:00:00` (Jan 2nd) becomes `01/02/2020` (Feb 1st)

How to convert them properly?

Comment: Have a look at [this function that will format a date in the dd/mm/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62215726/9663006). It may perform faster than your current method but I've not tested with any large data sets so give it a try and see how you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off handling this by properly importing the CSV file.  Especially if you use Power Query, you can designate the format of the incoming date at the time of import, and it will be correctly converted to a proper date/time value.

If that is not possible, this function, which you can incorporate into your code, will convert a string in your designated format into a proper date/time value, which you can then format as you wish.

Although the code could be shortened, I posted it in this manner so you can understand better the logic:

The code does no error checking and may give unpredictable results, or errors, if the input is not a **STRING** in the designated format. If necessary, you could error checking to the code.

```
Option Explicit
Function strToDate(S As String) As Date
    Dim arr, arrDt, m As Long, d As Long, y As Long
    
arr = Split(S, " ")
arrDt = Split(arr(0), ".")
    d = arrDt(0)
    m = arrDt(1)
    y = arrDt(2)
    
strToDate = DateSerial(y, m, d) + CDate(arr(1))

End Function
```

Here are examples using the data you posted, but formatting the output in an unambiguous manner.

[image]

Note that if you just want to return the Date portion, and exclude the Time portion, **and if your dates are all strings as you show**, you can just use the `Range.TextToColumns` method:

```
R.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("L1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=True, other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlDMYFormat), Array(2, xlSkipColumn))
```

In the above, you have previously `Set R` to the range to parse. `Destination` can be the same or a different column.  You split on the space; and then tell the TTC wizard to interpret the first column as DMY, and ignore the second column of the split (the time portion).

Answer (score -1):

You can try just select your cell and assign the format you want it to be. In your case I think you need dd/mm/yyyy, so it would be:

```
Range("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

You need to check that the value in the cell is not a string, or a =XX/XX/XXXX, just the value of the date. You will be able to fix that with code I guess, as all the cells will be in the same way.

Hope that helps.

If they are strings and you just want your column with your date format I suggest:

- Select the date column.
- Go to the Data-tab and choose "Text to Columns".
- On the first screen, leave radio button on "delimited" and click Next.
- Unselect any delimiter boxes (everything blank) and click Next.
- Under column data format choose Date
- Click Finish.
  Now you got date values, and you chose the wrong date format you can reset it in cell format, that should work because the cell is not a string anymore.
  If need to automate that task with VBA you can check what is the macro recorder code output for the user input seqcuence above, fix that a little and you got it.